# Resolve error NgFor only supports binding to Arrays

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have been getting the following error, where I am finding it hard to resolve. Can someone help me resolve this ?

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

The JSON Array

```
[{

    "studentname": "ddd",
    "age": 10,
    "school": {
        "s_name": "abc school",
        "school_city": "nsw"
    }
}]

<div   *ngFor="let stu of this.studentSelected; let i = index;" >
   <tr > <td>{{stu.studentname}} :</td>
         <ng-container *ngFor="let sof stu .school">
              <td>{{s.school_city}}</td>
          </ng-container>
   </tr>
</div>
```

I know that the error states NgFor only supports binding to Arrays. But, I don't see how I can correct this code.

Comment: assuming the space is a typo on the question the property stu.school is not an array

Answer (score 0):

well the direct answer to your question is to make `school` an array.

in your code you do `ngFor` on `stu.school` which is not an array, so just modify that line:

```js
studentSelected = [{
    "studentname": "ddd",
    "age": 10,
    "schools": [
      {
        "s_name": "abc school",
        "school_city": "nsw"
      }
    ]
}];
```

and your code will not show any errors:

```html
<div *ngFor="let stu of studentSelected; let i = index;" >
   <tr > 
     <td>{{stu.studentname}} :</td>
         <ng-container *ngFor="let s of stu.schools">
              <td>{{s.school_city}}</td>
         </ng-container>
   </tr>
</div>
```

this is a working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ikeuky?file=src/app/app.component.ts

please have a look :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the data provided, the `school` is an object and not an array so you don't need to loop over. You can directly use it like:

```
<div *ngFor="let stu of this.studentSelected; let i = index;">
  <tr>
    <td>{{stu.studentname}} :</td>
    <td>{{stu.school['school_city']}}</td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

I have created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2n8ri4?file=src/app/app.component.html) for this change and it's working. Please verify..

If `school` is an array, use ngFor and it won't give the above errors..